# Problema acceso datos JSON

Tags: javascript, json, jsonobject

estoy teniendo problemas para acceder a los datos de un `JSONObject` en `javascript` obtenido a partir de un `array` **`PHP`**.

Si hago un `console.log()` de todos los datos:

```
console.log(colors);
```

imprime:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Light Black","code":"#282525","color_palette_id":1,"created_at":"2019-08-25 17:29:06","updated_at":"2019-08-25 17:29:06","deleted_at":null},
...
{"id":6,"name":"Ocean Blue 2","code":"#0F97C2","color_palette_id":2,"created_at":"2019-08-25 17:29:06","updated_at":"2019-08-25 17:29:06","deleted_at":null}]
```

**Nota**: los puntos suspensivos los he puesto para reducir el trazado.

Si a continuación trato de obtener un elemento:

```
console.log(colors[0]);
```

imprime sólo el signo de apertura `[`.

Ocurre lo mismo si obtengo el **`JSON`**, así:

```
<script>
    var colors = JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($colors); <?);
    ...
</script>
```

o así:

```
<script>
    var colors = '<?php echo json_encode($colors); <?';
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: te muestra `[` porque es una cadena de texto, si lo quieres ver intenta algo como `console.log(typeof(colors))`si te devuelve string sabes que te falta transformar el JSON a Objeto intenta `var colors = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($colors); ?>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el método `parse`, para convertir la cadena de texto en un arreglo `JS`.

```
var colors = JSON.parse("stringEnJson");
console.log(colors[0]);
```

Mira este snippet:

```js
const array = '[{"id":1,"name":"Light Black","code":"#282525","color_palette_id":1,"created_at":"2019-08-25 17:29:06","updated_at":"2019-08-25 17:29:06","deleted_at":null}]';

var colors = JSON.parse(array);
console.log(colors[0]);
```